AIC correction for unusual transformations of the response
When using transformations of the response variable, one should correct the AIC of the transformed model in order to be possible to compare it to the unstransformed model (see here). The example used there is for the log transformation.
Now I want to test a different, unusual transformation on my dataset. I call this function rsqrt:
rsqrt <- function(x) -10*x^(-1/2)
If I understood it correctly, the AIC correction is pretty easy, one just need to derivate rsqrt and log the sum of the response transformed with this derivate. So, if I got it right, it should be enough to sum the uncorrected AIC with the term below, since the derivate of rsqrt can be written as 5/x^(3/2).
-2*sum(log(5/resp^(3/2))
I have tested this solution and it appears to me that it works fine (see R code below), I am just not so secure that it is  correct.
Thanks in advance for the answers.
rsqrt <- function(x) -10*x^(-1/2)
rsqr <- function(x) 100*x^(-2) # inverse of rsqrt

set.seed(1)
Area <- rnorm(n = 50, mean = 360, sd = 100)

VU <- rsqr(5000 -5*Area + rnorm(n = 50, mean = 360, sd = 100))
DF <- data.frame(VU, Area)

linFit <- lm(VU ~ Area, DF)                # "wrong" fit
transFit <- lm(rsqrt(VU) ~ Area, DF)       # "right" fit

AIC(linFit)
AIC(transFit)

k <- linFit$df.residual
n <- length(linFit$residuals)
p <- n - k - 1
K <- 2 + p

AIC_linFit <- 2*K - 2*logLik(linFit) # equals AIC(linFit) = -1266.694

AIC_transFit <- 2*K - 2*logLik(transFit) # equals AIC(transFit) = 604.4253

# Corrected AIC for transformed fit:
AIC_transFit1 <- 2*K - 2*logLik(transFit) - 2*sum(log(5/DF$VU^(3/2)))
# -1313.003 (seems good to me!)


The derivative of f(x) = -10x^(-1/2) is f'(x) = 5x^(-3/2) = 5/x^(+3/2). It does not seem incorrect to me!
